# DOM Exception 11: This Transaction is already finalized. Transactions are commited after its success or failure handlers are called ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic2

Can we use one SQLite transaction for two operation SELECT and INSERT?

### We tried by the following but the following error occurs ->

DOM Exception 11: This Transaction is already finalized. Transactions are commited after its success or failure handlers are called

### ionic

```
this.databaseService.executeQuery(async transaction => {
    let result = await transaction.executeSql(‘select * from TABLE0’)
    if (result == 0) {
         transaction.executeSql(‘INSERT INTO TABLE1 (TBL_NAME,PREFIX, NUMBER) values 
(?,?,?)’, [‘tbl_customer’, ‘tbl_customer’, 1])
         .catch(error => {
              alert("Error " + error.message);
         })
     }
}).catch(error => {
     let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: ‘App initialize error’,
        message: ‘initialize error’,
        cssClass: ‘error-alert’,
        buttons: [‘OK’]
   });
   alert.present();
})
```